# Доступ к wmi

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

Добрый день. У меня назрела проблема с возможностью доступа к WMI, точнее у разных учетных записей к некоторым полям WMI разный приоритет доступа, вследствие чего я могу получить от имени администратора нужные данные, а от пользователя - только частично, и это уже сказывается на работоспособности программы. Как можно обойти подобный запрет со стороны Windows, если запуск программы происходит от имени пользователя?

P. S. Не раз наблюдал решение подобной проблемы в c++, Delphi и т. д., а как схожее можно реализовать в C#?

Comment: Вы хотите получить расширенный функционал доступа к системе от имени обычного пользователя? Это нарушение прав доступа на уровне ОС. Если даже и есть какой-то работающий пример, о котором вы говорите, то он должен работать и под .net , так как wmi синтаксис запросов одинаков везде.

Comment: @MelnikovI Оформите комментарий в виде ответа, он ведь правильный :)

Answer (score 1):

Что касается получения расширенного доступа непосредственно к системе - уже ответил @Melnikovl, но, возможно, вы имели в виду запрет доступа к данным и инструментам WMI: не все данные и инструменты могут быть доступны текущему пользователю из программы, как правило, нельзя создавать кастомный класс и т.д.
В этом случае необходимо либо расширить полномочия текущего пользователя, либо создать нового и делегировать такие полномочия ему. Сделать это можно так:

1. Запустите `compmgmt.msc` с правами администратора. Правый клик на строку `Службы и приложения/Управляющий элемент WMI` и выберите `Свойства`.
2. Откройте вкладку `Безопасность` и перейдите в пространство имен. Выберите нужное, нажмите кнопку `Безопасность`.
3. Выберите группу или пользователя, доступ которых требуется настроить, и установите флажок `Разрешить` или `Запретить` в определенных полях, чтобы задать разрешение.

Либо можно это сделать с помощью powershell (из него можно выкинуть многие строки, но привычка логировать свои действия - хорошая привычка):

```
write-host “VicoNT:Start”
write-host “Разрешаю расширенный доступ к ветке root/cimv2 для всех пользователей”
write-host “”

# Cоздаю конструкцию для доступа к SDDL
$newPermissions = "O:BAG:BAD:P(A;CI;CCDCLCSWRPWPRCWD;;;BA)(A;CI;CC;;;NS)(A;CI;CC;;;LS)(A;CI;CC;;;BU)"
$converter = new-object system.management.ManagementClass Win32_SecurityDescriptorHelper
$binarySD = $converter.SDDLToBinarySD($newPermissions)
$convertedPermissions = ,$binarySD.BinarySD

# получаю объект для раздачи полномочий
$security = gwmi -namespace root/cimv2 -class __SystemSecurity

# беру текущие разрешения
$binarySD = @($null)
$result = $security.PsBase.InvokeMethod("GetSD",$binarySD)

$outsddl = $converter.BinarySDToSDDL($binarySD[0])
write-host "Предыдущие права: "$outsddl.SDDL

# меняю уровень доступа в SDDL
$result = $security.PsBase.InvokeMethod("SetSD",$convertedPermissions) 

# получаю уже новые полномочия 
$binarySD = @($null)
$result = $security.PsBase.InvokeMethod("GetSD",$binarySD)

$outsddl = $converter.BinarySDToSDDL($binarySD[0])
write-host "Новые права:      "$outsddl.SDDL
write-host “VicoNT:end”
```