# Создание кастомного класса в WMI

Tags: windows, классы, wmi

Всем привет! Подскажите, кто знает, как можно создать свой класс WMI и положить в него свои данные. Использую Microsoft Visual Studio 2012(5). Если не сложно, то прошу показать исходный код.

Answer (score 1):

*По-хорошему, нужно понять, имеет ли смысл создавать новый класс, зачем он нужен, нельзя ли решить задачу другим способом. WMI - мощный и зачастую очень необходимый инструмент, но внедрять в него всё подряд - не очень хорошая идея. Но вернёмся к вопросу.*

Сразу оговорюсь, я буду отвечать, имея в виду программирование на Delphi: я всё ещё не считаю себя достаточно сильным в C++/C#, чтобы работать с WMI на этих языках. С другой стороны, подход будет очень похожим, особенно для C#.

Для начала стоит почитать азы. Официальная [справка MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) понадобится в любом случае, но начинать с неё весьма тяжело. Стоит, на мой взгляд начать с чего-то более понятного: [Описание 1](http://www.script-coding.com/WMI.html), [Описание 2](http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogID=698), [Описание 3](http://microsin.net/adminstuff/windows/wmi.html). Пусть по этим ссылкам и очень мало сведений непосредственно о кастомных классах в WMI, зато сложится понимание, как инструментария, так и подходов к нему.

Также рекомендую обратить внимание на, пусть и устаревший, но полезный инструмент - [WMI Code creator](https://github.com/RRUZ/wmi-delphi-code-creator/blob/master/Units/WMI/uWmi_Metadata.pas), позволяющий сэкономить массу времени (он, кстати, генерирует код не только на Delphi, но и на C++, C#, Oxygene.

Начните с того, что определите в каком пространстве имён вы будете работать, выберите имя, создайте сам класс, определите все его элементы, проверьте его в работе. Например, создать простой класс можно так:

```
procedure CreateMyWMIClass(host,path,user,pass:string);

// host - localhost или компьютер в сети
// path - к пространству имён, например, 'root\CIMV2'

var
  MyLocator  : OLEVariant;
  MyService    : OLEVariant;
  MyObject    : OLEVariant;
begin
  try
     // обращаемся к интерфейсу SWbemLocator для создания нового класса
     MyLocator := CreateOleObject( 'WbemScripting.SWbemLocator' );
     // определяем
     MyService   := MyLocator.ConnectServer(host,path,user,pass);
     MyObject   := MyService.Get();
     MyObject.Path_.&Class := 'VicoNT_MyClass';
     MyObject.Properties_.Add('id',   wbemCimtypeUint8 );
     MyObject.Properties_.Add('text', wbemCimtypeString );
     MyObject.Properties_.Item('id').Qualifiers_.Add('key', true);
     MyObject.Put_;
  except
     On e: EOleException do begin
        //...
     end;

     On e: Exception do begin
        Exit;
     end;
  end;

  MyObject:=Unassigned;
end;
```

Вызывая процедуру, не забываем об инициализации:

```
  try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      CreateMyWMIClass('.','root\CIMV2','','');
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
```

Как правило, по умолчанию метод Put вернёт ошибку "Доступ запрещён". Чтобы разрешить добавление собственного класса, нужно разрешить текущему пользователю запись в пространство имён, с которым вы работаете. Я уже показывал, как это можно сделать в [данном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/371578/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-wmi/770547#770547).

Вот, кстати, интересный инструмент для создания класса в powershell: [PowerShell WMI module](http://powershelldistrict.com/how-to-create-custom-wmi-classes-and-properties-with-powershell-wmi-module/)

Когда отработаете свой класс, определите все данные, устраните все ошибки, можно подумать и о создании и компиляции MOF-файла. Вначале читайте [быстрый подход](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/27914/webcontrols/), а затем уже [оф. справку Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389240%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).