# Восстановление работы Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) после фатального сбоя

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-10, powershell, wmi

На компьютере под управлением Windows 10 перестала работать `WMI`.
Никакие скрипты, раньше нормально работавшие, теперь не функционируют. Диапазон возвращаемых ошибок достаточно велик: **0x80041XXX**, **0x800420XX**, **0x700310XX** (“**Инициализация класса WMI невозможна**”, “**Вызов WMI запрещен**”, “**WMI вернул некорректный ответ**”, "**Ошибка в файле WMI.MOF**" и так далее).

Возможно ли это исправить? Почему это произошло? Если нет, то можно ли работать без функционирующего `WMI`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Я столкнулся с этой ситуацией на днях: мои студенты тестировали управление системными функциями и две машины в домене (на обеих – Windows 10) стали возвращать ошибки при работе с Windows Management Instrumentation. Основной админ ещё не вышел из отпуска, пришлось вспоминать, что я бывший руководитель Отдела ИТ :)*

Сразу отвечу на **третий вопрос**: без рабочего WMI, на мой взгляд, можно оставлять лишь домашний игровой компьютер, на котором, кроме игр и просмотра видео, больше ничего не делается (разве что дети учатся программировать). В остальных случаях, особенно на корпоративных машинах, тем более в домене, WMI должна работать как часы. Это моё мнение, кто-то может не согласиться.

Теперь о причинах произошедшего: их может быть очень много. Забегая вперед, скажу что на одной машине это произошло из-за того, что на жестком диске закончилось место, а затем был сбой по питанию из-за сломанного ИБП (увы, никто не застрахован; сервера, конечно, защищены от подобного, а обычная рабочая машинка не была). На второй хуже: нефатальный сбой жесткого диска с последующим BSOD. В целом, разобраться с причинами не так уж и важно, главное, выяснить, что причиной не является вирус или попытка взлома. Впрочем, намеренное удаление или случайная порча системных файлов тоже должны быть рассмотрены достаточно пристально.

Восстановление работоспособности WMI следует проводить **поэтапно**, от щадящих методов к деструктивным. Следует быть готовым к тому, что в самом худшем случае систему придётся переустановить. Не стоит лишний раз напоминать, что большинство команд должно выполняться от имени администратора.

**1 этап. Проверка работы сервиса.**

Проверяем имеется ли в системе служба `Windows Management Instrumentation (Winmgmt)` и включена ли она. Вызываем Службы (в Windows 10 проще всего через **Пуск/Средства администрирования/Службы**, но я предпочитаю в любой версии Windows, кроме самых старых, напечатать в командной строке `services.msc`), ищем `Инструментарий управления Windows/Windows Management Instrumentation`, проверяем, запущена ли она:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если она не запущена, пытаемся запустить, выставим режим запуска в «Автоматически». Если запущена, пытаемся перезапустить (Остановить/запустить). После этого проверяем работоспособность WMI. Проще всего сделать это, выполнив любой WMI-запрос в `powershell` (напоминаю, что powershell в Windows 10 запускается через **Пуск/Windows PowerShell/Windows Power Shell**, но проще, на мой взгляд, запустить командную строку с админовскими правами, а в ней уже набрать `powershell`), например, такой: (вы можете выполнить другой, свой любимый :))

```
Get-WmiObject -List -ComputerName localhost
```

Если у вас вылетела портянка объектов, всё в порядке. Если же полезли ошибки, значит, работоспособность не восстановлена, переходим ко второму этапу.

Между делом скажу пару слов об официальной утилите  [Microsoft WMI Diagnosis](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7684). Все почему-то наперебой её рекомендуют, как хороший помощник при восстановлении. Увы, я убил достаточно много времени на анализ результатов действия этой утилиты: скрипт создал кучу лог-файлов, через которые продраться можно, если вы никуда не торопитесь, у вас есть куча времени и полкило пуэра/кофе-машина. В причинах сбоев я разобрался быстрее без неё. Вероятность того, что она может помочь непосредственно в скором восстановлении работы WMI – очень мала.

**2 этап. Недеструктивное восстановление**

Стоит попытаться вначале выполнить перерегистрацию библиотек и рекомпиляцию файлов расширения свойств объектов (`Managed Object Format, MOF`) и языковую составляющую этих файлов (`MFL`). Практически гарантированно сработает, если попытка WMI-запроса у вас вызывала ошибку вида “Ошибка в файле WMI.MOF” или любом другом MOF-файле. Для этого выполним следующие операции:

1. Остановим службу WMI, обязательно запретив её автостарт
2. Перерегистрируем все библиотеки в папке Windows\system32\wbem
3. Перерегистрируем службы WMI и WMI Provider Host
4. Запускаем службу WMI и разрешаем её автостарт
5. Рекомпилируем MOF и MFL файлы

Можно собрать всё это в один BAT-файл и запустить:

```
# пункт 1
sc config winmgmt start= disabled
net stop winmgmt
# пункт 2
cd %windir%\system32\wbem
for /f %%s in ('dir /b *.dll') do regsvr32 /s %%s
#пункт 3
wmiprvse /regserver
winmgmt /regserver
#пункт 4
sc config winmgmt start= auto
net start winmgmt
#пункт 5
for /f %%s in ('dir /b *.mof') do mofcomp %%s
for /f %%s in ('dir /b *.mfl') do mofcomp %%s
```

Отмечу, что таким образом я восстановил работу WMI на первой машине. Со второй, увы не получилось. Если у вас не получается, пора переходить к 3му этапу

**3 этап. Деструктивное восстановление**

Фактически, на 3м этапе мы пересоздаем хранилище WMI, как таковое, которое находится в папке  **Windows\System32\Wbem\Repository** и является базой данных, в которой хранятся данные и определения стандартных WMI-классов и статическая информация дополнительных WMI-классов, если они создавались на вашей машине.

**Перед операциями проверьте состояние жёсткого диска и файловой системы!!!**

Проверяем целостность (На Windows XP и ниже не работает):

```
winmgmt /verifyrepository
```

В случае ответа отличного от “База данных WMI согласована”, можно выполнить "мягкое восстановление" командой:

```
winmgmt /salvagerepository
```

с последующим перезапуском службы:

```
net stop Winmgmt
net start Winmgmt
```

Если мягкое восстановление не помогло, пробуем вернуть хранилище в начальное состояние (последствия: все дополнительные классы WMI, когда-либо зарегистрированные в вашей системе, скорее всего, придётся регистрировать заново):

```
winmgmt /resetrepository
```

с последующим рестартом системы. Отмечу, что вторая машина заработала после этого этапа. Последствия были не сильно удручающими, но серьёзными: пришлось переинсталлировать Visual Studio и Delphi Starter, MS Office отказался работать и его пришлось деинсталлировать вручную, удаляя папки, файлы и записи из реестра, с последующей повторной установкой. Также слетели все наши собственные классы WMI.

Но, если и это не помогло, придётся удалять и создавать хранилище заново. Это можно сделать следующим BAT-файлом:

```
# Остановим службу WMI, обязательно запретив её автостарт
sc config winmgmt start= disabled
net stop winmgmt
# проводим реинициализацию WMI
cd %windir%\system32\wbem
winmgmt /kill
winmgmt /unregserver
winmgmt /regserver
winmgmt /resyncperf
# создаем на всякий случай резервную копию нашего хранилища в папку WMI_VicoNT_Backup
# у вас, разумеется, может быть другое имя папки
if exist WMI_VicoNT_Backup rd WMI_VicoNT_Backup /s /q
rename Repository Repos_bakup
# воссоздаем хранилище
regsvr32 /s %systemroot%\system32\scecli.dll
regsvr32 /s %systemroot%\system32\userenv.dll
for /f %%s in ('dir /b *.dll') do regsvr32 /s %%s
for /f %%s in ('dir /b *.mof') do mofcomp %%s
for /f %%s in ('dir /b *.mfl') do mofcomp %%s
# запускаем службу WMI, заново регистрируем WMI Provider Host
sc config winmgmt start= auto
net start winmgmt
wmiprvse /regserver
```

Перегружаем компьютер. Если и после этих действий WMI не заработала, путь один – переустановка системы.

Comment: Можно ли при помощи "мягкого решения" добавлять собственные классы в репозиторий WMI?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Это, как "использовать секвенатор для забивания гвоздей" :) . Скомпилировать MOF можно проще: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/684352/